# How to create log4net log file in a platform independent path and outside of compiled assemblies folder

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I have the "File" param value set as below in the log4net.config.

```
<param name="File" value="Logger.log"/>
```

And the Logger.log file is created in the folder of compiled assemblies. I want the logger to be created outside of the bin folder, and also I do not want to provide the fully qualified path, since I want it to be platform independent. Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Where **do** you want the file to be created?

Comment: I want the logger file to be created anywhere in the project directory but not inside the compiled assemblies directory.

Comment: But when the app is deployed, there won't be a project directory?

Comment: I don't know log4net.
`<param name="File" value="C:\Folder\Logger.log"/>` doesn't work?

Comment: @MiguelCosta OP wants a platform-independent solution.

Answer (score 1):

With in the `FileAppender` it's possible to define the file path using properties defined elsewhere. In this example, the `LogPath` property can be supplied by your application via the `log4net.GlobalContext`:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogPath}Logger.log" />
```

Set the value of the property before calling the `XmlConfigurator`:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogPath"] = @"C:\SomePath\";
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```